# How can I open a new window inside a script, ssh to a different user and run commands?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ssh, xterm

I want to open a new terminal with minicom or ssh connection and run commands with a different user in that new window, using a shell script. 
I tried inside the shell script to write the following commands:

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh -f
    set Flag1 = 1  
    while ($Flag1) 
           if ($Flag1)then 
                  `xterm -e /home/Script/First.sh`
                  set Flag1 = 0
           endif 
    end
```

The `/home/Script/First.sh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/tcsh -f
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
ifconfig eth0 10.120.140.3
ping -w20 10.120.140.1
```

The first command (minicom) worked, but it didn't continue to the other ones.

Comment: Why do you need this to be done in a new terminal? Why not simply run the script? And what language is that? It isn't bash.

Comment: I need to run commands that will remain running while i"m continue the scrip in the main shell.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new window inside a script you can use `xterm` as you have done. It's not recommended use the 'sudo' command inside a script.

So, instead of run the script `First.sh` with sudo inside, run:

```
sudo /usr/bin/tcsh
```

and remove `sudo` from `minicom`in the file `First.sh`.

It doesn't seem to be the case, but there are situations where adding the `-hold` option to the command `xterm` prevents the script to stop the execution.

**1. If you can use ssh** it's pretty straightforward.

```
ssh -t user@ip 'ifconfig eth0 10.120.140.3; ping -w20 10.120.140.1'
```

**2) If you need to use minicom** you should store your script in the destination to allow the execution.

```
sudo vi First.txt
```

Paste **only** the following lines:

```
ifconfig eth0 10.120.140.3
ping -w20 10.120.140.1
```

There were situations that minicon did not accepted shell scripts and adding a `!` before solved the problem, as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529535/running-a-script-with-minicom-unknown-command-echo?noredirect=1#comment979975_529535)

Then, open it's 'console-gui' and send to the destination:

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
send atz
send at
```

You should receive an answer 'OK' in the last two commands.

Then run your script with:

```
minicom -S First.txt
```